# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with Jest for React-Chat-Widget

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, widget, react-testing-library

I am trying the test the App component within our widget and when running the test I come up with this error. This is all new to me by the way, just started learning to do tests this week for work.

> Jest encountered an unexpected token

```
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/Users/*******/******/chat-widget/src/chatWidget/index.js:3
import ConnectedWidget from './src/index';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  40 |     setSessionId,
  41 |     updateTextAction,
> 42 |     setShowDeliveryInput,
     |                  ^
  43 |     setShowManyItems,
  44 |     setRetailerId,
  45 |     setBrandId,
```

I'm found the file that is causing problem ( I commented out the file and the error was gone ) and I tried using [**testPathIgnorePatterns**](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testpathignorepatterns-array-string) but it didn't seem to work how I wrote it. I thought that maybe ignoring that file that was being imported into the App component would be the answer.

```
"jest" : {
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "<rootDir>/src/index.js"
        ]
    },
```

I'm not quite sure what else to do as this is new to me. Thank you for your help.enter code here

Comment: The message states the opposite, you should use transformIgnorePatterns for malfunctioning node_modules, not your own modules. The error means that Babel wasn't correctly configured. If done properly, it's used by default by Jest, no additional Jest config is needed. Check the manual first, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started